# How to debug C# without breakpoints in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I'm having trouble to find the statement that causes a given side-effect. I put a breakpoint in every class member and I still can't make the execution pause on the culprit line.

- Is there a debugger option that makes the execution to pause at every line regardless of breakpoints?

or

- How to make every line a breakpoint without the effort of marking them manually?

Comment: What sort of side effect is it? There may be better ways to trap this problem, or set more likely breakpoints.

Comment: @Damien something my code does, makes Windows verify the code signature against updated CRLs and STLs on the internet, if there is an Internet connection available.

Comment: What's the side effect that you're trying to trap?  It might be easier to look at the problem another way.

Comment: @Dan look at my answer to Damien

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on the first line of the *side effect* method, and then when execution breaks, check out the Call Stack to see (at least one of the ways) how you got there.

Comment: @Cody I don't know which line causes the *side effect*.

Comment: I didn't mean the line that *caused* it, I meant whatever you're describing as *being* the side effect. If you know what the side effect is, and don't know what caused it, you could approach it from the other way around. I suppose I'm assuming this side effect is not something that is entirely external to your code. Maybe that's a poor assumption.

Comment: @Cody it is entirely external to my code. Windows accepts my code signature, until I do something that makes it to want to verify if it is expired.

Comment: Is it definitely checking your signature, and not some other assembly? Are you using any 3rd party controls? Can you flesh out your question with the type of application (you've said event driven - but asp.net or winforms, or something weird?), and (if necessary) the deployment method.

Comment: @Jader This is one reason to use logging in your application, a logging approach is often critical to debugging an application that has gone awry

Comment: @Aaron I don't believe logging can solve this particular problem. And I use it already.

Comment: @Damien I'm sure it's my assembly signature, albeit I'm using 3rd party controls. I'm using WPF, the same problem doesn't happen with simpler WPF desktop apps with the same deployment method.

Comment: @Jader Logging may not solve the problem outright but it should lead you to the problem. Dealing with an application out in the field where a developer needs to run through the debugger often times is not viable.

Comment: @Jader: as far as I can see, you still haven't said *what your side effect is*, other than hinting that it's something multi-threaded.  Until you do it's hard to suggest anything useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pause execution, and then start tracing line by line (e.g. by pressing F10). This would give you the exact same effect of breaking at every line.

**Edit**: You won't have to put a breakpoint in each method is you use "trace into" (by pressing F11 in default settings). Then the debugger will stop in the first line of the method being called.

If you're having trouble debugging it, maybe before going for breakpoints some more static analysis is required... Can you describe the side effect you are trying to hunt down? Maybe then people can offer suggestions on how to find it or at least narrow the search.

**Edit 2**: I don't think you will find the side effect you described through a breakpoint. The verification of signed code is done by the CLR when you load a signed assembly. It has to access the network in order to update revocation lists.

To workaround this problem you can disable CRL checking. Here's some info on how to do it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738754(WS.10).aspx

Of course, you should be aware of the security implications (what if the certificate for the code you are running *really* was revoked?)

Comment: Yes I know. It work only if I set a breakpoint in the first line of each method. I tried it already and it is cumbersome and not so effective.

Comment: +1 for pausing execution in a particular place. You can do this anywhere like in MessageBoxes etc, very useful.

Comment: @Jader Dias, I understand the certificate wasn't revoked. I thought what bothered you was the check itself, and the access to the network that was done in order to update the CRL.

Comment: @Ran the CRL is not my main concern, since I can download and install them manually, solving part of the problem for a few months. But I can't do the same with the STL. Even if I download and install it, a given machine will continue to search for it.

Comment: So this is not really a Visual Studio debugging issue, since the effect you are hunting isn't happening in your code and you won't be able to break into it. I suggest you add some more information about your problem with the STL, what you were trying to do and what went wrong.

Comment: @Ran If I comment a given class and all references to it, the problem is solved. How it cannot be debuggable?

Comment: @Jader Dias, because this class probably has a reference to another class, so that in order to JIT that class the CLR now has to load an assembly that wasn't loaded before. And then it has to verify the signing of this new assembly.

Comment: what doesn't make sense is the fact the problem only occurs if my assembly is signed.

Comment: "You can pause execution"
Great idea, but how can I pause it on the very start?

Answer (score 3):

Put a breakpoint on the first line of your code that gets executed (e.g. the first line of your main function, if you're a console application). Then just use the single-step commands (F10 and F11, by default) to walk through the execution.

Comment: It would work for a single threaded app. And what about an event driven multi threaded app?

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty easy but only if you know what is going on.  Here is what to do.

1. In Visual Studio with your project open hold *ctrl-alt-E* to load the Exceptions dialog.
   This gives you options for when to break.  You will select "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" Thrown column.
2. Now go ahead and run your application.  Now any CLR exceptions that are thrown will take you to the line of code that broke.

Don't forget to ctrl-alt-E and uncheck when your done!

[image: screenshot here!]

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, so long as the code you're trying to debug is throwing an exception. The way the question is worded, he's trying to find the code that causes certain side effects, which doesn't necessarily mean it's throwing an exception.

Comment: @Jader Diaz Yeah... after read all the comments I see what's up...  There is no way to have all of them at once.  What happens is that you can have it break at any 1 point while your debugging and any subsequent points that break will come to the front of your debug session.

Comment: You can use conditional breakpoints, break on exception, DebugBreak, Debug.Write and some others but debugging multi-threaded scenarios is much more difficult because the process may return at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the built in Break All feature of the debugger.  It doesn't apply to every situation, but if it applies to yours, then it's very simple to use.  Debug >> Break All (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>)

See the section titled "Break into code by using breakpoints or Break All" on this page for more information: [Start, Break, Step, Run through Code, and Stop Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try just stepping over the code with F10 until you hit the problem, it would have the same outcome.

Comment: see my comments to similar answers

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem. 
You can use one breakpoint and then hit F10 (Step over) or F11 (Step into) to go the next instruction. That would be the same as having a breakpoint on every line and hitting F5 (continue) after each break.
Or you can set a breakpoint at the culprit line and investigate the callstack window to see the control flow up to that point.

Comment: I don't know which is the culprit line. That's exactly what I am looking for.